# Adding data onto new row Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

in this code, I'm trying to add product data and update inventory level when i purchase more goods. I'm not exactly sure how i can add the product data onto the next row but my nextERow is returning '0' instead of the next empty row value. Is there anyway i can fix this??

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
With Worksheets("Inventory List")
    'update quantity if there is an existing product
    If .Cells(nextERow, 2).Value = nameTextBox.Text Then
        .Cells(nextERow, 3).Value = .Cells(nextERow, 3).Value + quantityTextBox.Value

    'insert product on a new row if current row is not empty
    ElseIf Len(.Cells(nextERow, 2).Value) > 0 Then
        .Cells(nextERow, 2).Value = nameTextBox.Text
        .Cells(nextERow, 3).Value = quantityTextBox.Value
        .Cells(nextERow, 4).Value = priceTextBox.Text

    'insert product if current row is empty
    ElseIf IsEmpty(.Cells(nextERow, 2)) Then
        .Cells(nextERow, 2).Value = nameTextBox.Text
        .Cells(nextERow, 3).Value = quantityTextBox.Value
        .Cells(nextERow, 4).Value = priceTextBox.Text
    End If
End With
End Sub

Function nextERow() As Integer
    nextERow = Worksheets("Inventory List").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
End Function
```

Comment: `nextERow = Worksheets("Inventory List").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Two suggestions. Qualify `Rows.Count` like ` Worksheets("Inventory List").Rows.Count` and declare nextERow as a `Long` to allow for all rows.

Comment: (a) Do you have anything in column A?  (But that doesn't explain why it returns 0 - if you had nothing in column A it should return 2.)  (b) Is `Function nextERow` in the same code module as `Sub btnAdd_Click`?  (c) Do you have `Option Explicit` as the first line of all your code modules?  (If you don't, you should - it avoids lots of problems.)

Comment: (d) There are several things in your `nextERow` function that make it look like it has been typed into the question rather than copy/pasted (e.g. no space after the comma in `Rows.Count,1`, lowercase `r` in `.row`).  Is that line **exactly** what is in your code?

Comment: Your function will only return `0` if it errors.  I can see two possible reasons for an error: Worksheet `Inventory List` doesn't exist in the active workbook, or the number of rows in the active sheet > rows in `Inventory List`

Comment: @chrisneilsen - is it actually possible to have more rows in one worksheet in the active workbook than in another worksheet in the active workbook??  (If this code was in a Form, would `Rows.Count` do something weird, or would it still use the active worksheet?  I'd test it myself, but I am about to pack up for the day and go home.)

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, if one is xls and the other xlsx/m/b (strictly, if both are in the same (active) workbook then, No)